# Spacy Chunking prepositional verb with it's preposition

Tags: python, spacy

I'm new to using Spacy.
I need to chunk together in a sentence the prepositional verb (if exist) with it's preposition.
Example: "Get off"
I know i can use the POS to identify a verb and a ADP, and first I wanted to went on the rule of VERB+ADP that appear consecutively, but that is covering cases that the verb is stand alone regardless of the preposition.
Can you please support?

I tried the subtree and children options, but from what I saw, verb+prepositions that are not creating a prepositional verb (No new meaning) still will be considered part of the same phrase
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dependency attributes for this task.

For example, let's say you have the following sentence:

`You should get off the buss at the next stop, then you can wait on the right.`

The following code would print out `get off` but not `wait on`:

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher, DependencyMatcher

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

doc = nlp("You should get off the buss at the next stop up the road.")

matcher = DependencyMatcher(nlp.vocab)
pattern = [
    {
        "RIGHT_ID": "verb",
        "RIGHT_ATTRS": {"POS": "VERB"}
    },
    {
        "LEFT_ID": "verb",
        "REL_OP": ">",
        "RIGHT_ID": "prop",
        "RIGHT_ATTRS": {"DEP": "prt"}
    }
]
matcher.add("PROPOSITIONAL_VERB", [pattern])
matches = matcher(doc)

for match in matches:
    verb = doc[match[1][0]]
    prop = doc[match[1][1]]
    print(f'{verb} - {prop}')
```

For `get off`, the POS tags are as follows:

- get : VERB
- off : ADP

For `wait on`, this is exactly the same, so the POS tags are not helpful as you explained:

- wait : VERB
- on   : ADP

However, the dependency tags are inferred as follows by spaCy's small model, so they allow us to differentiate between two chunks and pick the one we need:

- get  : ccomp
- off  : prt
- wait : ROOT
- on   : prep

That's why the code example above uses POS tag for the verb but the dependency tag for the proposition.

You can review the following page to get an idea of the dependency matcher in spaCy: https://spacy.io/api/dependencyparser

I also strongly recommend you use the built-in dependency visualizer in spaCy to get a better idea of how dependency tags work: https://spacy.io/usage/visualizers

I hope this helps.